# What is the purpose of --replSet for mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver, bigchaindb

You can use `sudo mongod`, but also `sudo mongod --replSet=bigchain-rs`.

What is the main purpose of that flag? And where does data get stored in both cases.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I tried to reword your question to make more clear what you are actually asking about. Please review my changes. But I also agree to the comment given: it feels like your question is not on topic here. And probably it is lacking some prior research, too.

Answer (score 0):

With BigchainDB 2.0+, you don't have to set the name of the MongoDB replica set any more. That was something you used to have to do with previous versions of BigchainDB, because those versions worked very differently: they *always* involved a BigchainDB replica set. Now a replica set is optional and usually not needed / overkill.